# notification bar is not responding while downloading an item using java thread in android

Tags: android, download, notifications, progress-bar, java-threads

I'm using java thread to download a zip file from an API.when i start download a file,the download progress will be displayed in the notification bar.when i scroll down the notification bar,it have no response.it just hang the device till the download complete.if download is done, then no problem in scroll notification bar.

my question is :

1.how to make the app run smoothly without any lag?is there any other way to handle download progress in android.

```
2.the app take some time to start download.is there any problem with the code that i am using.
```

here is my code :

---

```
 protected void doDownload(final String urlLink, final String fileName) {


        final Thread dx = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/EriReader/temp/");
                if (dir.exists() == false) {
                    dir.mkdirs();

                }
                //Save the path as a string value
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlLink);
                    Log.i("FILE_NAME", "File name is " + fileName);
                    Log.i("FILE_URLLINK", "File URL is " + url);
                    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
                    final int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                    // download the file
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dir + "/" + fileName);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        if (fileLength > 0) {
                             int status = ((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

                       //    Notification in notification bar
                            mBuilder.setProgress(100, status, false);
                            mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
                        }
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("DOWNLOADING err", "ERROR IS" + e);
                }


                mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                        // Removes the progress bar
                        .setProgress(0, 0, false);
                mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

            }

        };
}
```

Comment: Use an AsyncTask instead of a thread.

Comment: but using async task for downloading larger file is not good i think.

Comment: you have made a thread,and thread is not used for UI update ,here you are always trying to notify  mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());  so the notification bar is hanging until thread stop.

Comment: @Amit Ranjan: Can u show how to update the UI thread in my code?

Answer (score 0):

[You can follow this link:you have to use AsyncTask for the UI updation in on Post Method](https://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/)

Comment: dn't forgot to upvote :) if you get proper answer :)